# Connecting to Web data source with credentials via Power BI

Tags: authentication, powerbi

I am trying to connect to a web site through Power BI so I can retrieve data from a table there.

This web site requires user id and password to login first

[image]

I tried connecting using the passowrd in the Basic form

[image]

but got invalid ( although they are the valid user id and password)

[image]

I used different ways as the last one i used was from here

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Connect-to-a-website-that-has-credential/td-p/21215/page/3

Here what I tried to do

I used the Web data source and when asked for URL i used the login url

https://SomeWebSite.com/UserLogin.aspx

I chose the advanced option to Authorization header first

[image]
I chose the "Basic" Access option

used the User id and password

[image]

after all that I still get an error can not connect

[image]

Comment: Can you reveal the website you're trying to log in or something about that website? Are you able to get information from other sites that need authentication?