# Get data from password protected Web

Tags: powerbi

I want to get data from a password protected website. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752735/connecting-to-web-data-source-with-credentials-via-power-bi) but no one ever responded to it. Does anyone know if it is possible to connect to a password protected website from Power BI? If yes, how?
Thanks!

Comment: First question is, does the site provide an api? If so, you should have a way of authenticating to the API instead of the website itself and pull the data from there.

Comment: Yes, but when I connect via API I have to create a dynamic url, which prevents me from automated refreshing in Power BI Service

Comment: Have a look at this https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/08/29/connecting-to-rest-apis-with-oauth2-authentication-in-power-query-power-bi/

Comment: It's not a straightforward thing to do at the moment. Other alternative would be to use Power Automate, to get the data out into a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments above from [Joao Leal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309027/joao-leal)
It can either be done with a custom connector or Power Automate

Answer (score 0):

I have always had 'getting data from a website with Password and a token authentication' a challenge for me. I basically extract to excel then Power Automate does the rest. However, there's something about PowerShell I am yet to explore...